# Finding the $p$ norm of a row matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $u \in \mathbb{C}^n$. It is well-known that $||u^*||_2 = ||u||_2$, where the norm on the LHS is the matrix norm and the norm on the RHS is the vector norm. I was trying to see if we can extend this to general $p$ norms. By Holder's inequality we have, for $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ with $||x||_p = 1$,
$$|u^*x| \le ||u||_{\frac {p}{p-1}}||x||_p = ||u||_{\frac {p}{p-1}}$$

So $||u^*|| \le ||u||_{\frac {p}{p-1}}$. But I have not been able to show equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q = \frac p{p-1}$. For $p \notin \{1,\infty\}$, take $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with
$$
x_j = \begin{cases}
\|u\|_q^{1-q} \cdot |u_j|^q/u_j & u_j \neq 0\\
0 & u_j = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Verify that we have $\|x\|_p = 1$ and $u^*x = \|u\|_q$.